# How to power a Shelly Uni in a computer system as a smart power switch

Tags: microcontroller, power

I have an Shelly Uni (https://shelly.cloud/products/shelly-uni-smart-home-automation-device/) device and I am wondering if I could turn it into a smart power switch, and what I would need to do so.

From what I understand is that the device is a smaller and low voltage version of a smart switch. What I am mostly wondering about is how to power the device from the computer.

The ATX molex connector there is a 5V standby, which I think can probably get splice together with ground on the molex to provide constant power of the Shelly Uni.

But what I am wondering about if this is safe to do or if it'll cause problems? I assume some of the load is drawn is ciphened away away from motherboard so I am not if this is generally safe or causes severe problems. Any thoughts?

Comment: What on earth is a shelly uni?

Comment: If it's a brand name or product shouldn't it be capitalised?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Please clarify.

Comment: What i am asking is that if i want to use 5v standby from the atx molex to power on an esp based microcontroller ( in my case Shelly Uni ) if this can safely be done or if this will cause problems with motherboard.

Comment: To clarify the 5v standby is a 5v that is always on, so this is used to give power to some elements in the computer already afaik but i dont know how safe it use to ciphen some power away from it.

Comment: As @justme mentioned, what leads you to think this device will run from 5V (standby or not)? According to the website it needs 12-36V.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the website you linked, the device needs 12V or more to work. It does not work with 5V.

Comment: Yeah this was a oversight on my part. I know that most esp devices run on 3.3v are 5v tolerant on gpio pins, so I assumed the shelly would have same power requirements. Let's say I could find a device satisfying power requirements, can you safely take some of the power from 5SVB line though?

Comment: It depends how much "some" is and can the power supply provide it. How can anyone answer that without knowing how much 5V current you need and how much 5V current can be provided by the power supply and how much 5V current is available after all the other components are consuming current too.

Answer (score 0):

### I don't think it'll work.

The standby power inside a PC is for "clock keep-alive" and other trivial loads.  It's not a general-use power supply to run something like a DC/DC converter, which you would need to turn your 5V into 12V.

### Just use a separate AC wall-wart.

Really, that is the solution that almost everyone would use in this situation.   Approved wall-warts are commodity items.

Remember those Shelly units are *not* for switching AC mains.  If you need to switch AC mains with a computer, use a wireless smart switch that is Listed by UL or other independent, recognized testing lab, and is either plug-in, or if hardwired have a licensed electrician install it.  Certain Shelly units are UL listed and are safe to use.

Comment: The problem is those molex connectors have no power when the computer is powered off, whereas the 5VSB has a constant power as long as the psu is connected to ac mains.

Comment: This answer does not relate to the standby scenario presented in the question.

Comment: @JustMe sorry I did not catch that. Fixed.

Comment: @LawrenceKok but the wrong voltage, and not enough to rely on. Edited, but you won't like it.